# Node.JS & Socket.IO - Prioritise / Pause & Resume

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, sockets

I am building a real time application using AngularJS, NodeJS & Socket.IO. The application facilitates 3-4 large tables which are populted from a MongoDB database and after the initial load they only get updated.

Each table store almost 15-30Mb of data and it takes about 30 seconds to populate them using Socket.IO . Now, if a user navigates to a different page before all data is downloaded, the data required by the new page stays in the queue and is received after the table from the first page populates in full. Is there a way to pause or cancel the request when navigating to a different page?

Thanks in advance for your help.

--- Edit ---

To make the question more clear, here is the process that a user might follow:

1. The User opens /index and Grid_1 starts loading with Data from the server using Socket.IO. The data is coming in chunks of 50 records at the time. Grid_1 will eventualy get populated with 15.000 records and it will take 30 to download all the data.
2. After the user waits at /index for 10 secords, he decides to visit /mySecondPage where there is Grid_2 which simillar with Grid_1 populates from the database with 15.000 records which takes 30 seconds to download - again using Socket.IO. Since the user switched from /index to /mySecondPage before the data is populated in Grid_1, Grid_2 is not populated with data before Grid_1's data is fully downloaded. Hope that made it more clear?

Comment: Please describe in more detail the exact sequence of events you're trying to work with.  I don't follow what is sent when and how that correlates with the user navigating to a new page and I don't understand exactly what problem you're trying to solve.  Your server will get a socket.io disconnect and then a new connection when the user navigates to a new page.

Comment: Please add this info to your question.